# How can I deal with multiple entities data in a single Azure Event Hub namespace?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have 30 entities in my system and going to publish these entities content into Azure Event Hubs, and let other downstream application to subscribe. 1 entity will be a single message. In my case I hope to create 30 topics for all these entities. However I found that 1 single Event Hub namespace can only support up to 10 Event Hubs (topics).

I am not preferring to create multiple namespaces for this, since it might be hard to maintain or manage them. (Also we need to keep a mapping of which entities goes to which namespace in downstream application)

Is there any ways/ suggestions to resolve it? Should I make use of the partitionId in Azure Event Hub? Like:

```
partitionId[1]: Entity 1
partitionId[2]: Entity 2
...
partitiionId[30]: Entity 30
```

Comment: To me, this sounds like it would align better with Service Bus, using topics and subscriptions.   May I ask the reason that you decided on Event Hubs?

Comment: @JesseSquire Mainly is the cost of service bus is much expensive than Event Hubs.

Comment: Resource isolation is preferred in my project so the Premium tier of Service Bus is required.